# I want to do message passing from web page to chrome extension html but seems no response is coming. Here is the code

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, extension-methods

Below is the code m trying but getting response null in popup. I want to do message passing from web page to chrome extension html .

**mainfest.json**

```
    {
            "manifest_version": 2,

            "name": "AnyName",
            "description": "A simple extension for Chrome",
            "version": "1.0",
            "author": "@aag",

            "background": {"scripts": ["background.js"]},

            "permissions":[
                "tabs", "http://*/*", "activeTab", "storage", "ftp://*/*", "<all_urls>", "clipboardWrite", "contentSettings", "cookies", "history"
                ],
            "page_action": {
           "default_icon": "logo.png" , 
           "default_popup": "popup.html"
          },
          "content_scripts": [
            {
              "matches": ["*://*/show_bug.cgi?id/*"],
              "js": ["content.js"],
              "run_at": "document_start"
            }]
        }
```

**popup.html**

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html>

    <head>
        <title>Extension</title>
        <script src="popup.js"></script>
        <script src="jquery.js"></script>

    </head>

    <body>
        <h3>Whiteboard!!</h1>
            <p id='pagetitle'>Page is still Loading..</p>
            <p id='reported'>Date is still Loading..</p>




    </body>

    </html>
```

**popup.js**

```
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {  
        prepareSummary();

    });

    function prepareSummary() {
        chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
            chrome.tabs.sendRequest(tab.id, {
                action: "getSummary"
            }, function(response) {
                if (response == null) {
                    alert('no respose');
                   } else {
                    var wbVar = response.wb;
                    var rdateVar = response.rd;

                    document.getElementById('pagetitle').innerHTML = wbVar;
                    document.getElementById('reported').innerHTML =rdateVar ;

                }
            });
        });

    }
```

**content.js**

```
    chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
         if (request.action == "getSummary") {
            var wbVar = document.getElementById('status_whiteboard').value;
            var rdateVar = document.getElementsByClassName("bz_comment_time")[0].innerText;
                sendResponse({  
                wb: wbVar,
                rd: rdateVar,
                resp: "Test"
            });
        } else
            sendResponse({
                resp: "Nothing"
            });
    });
```

**background.js**

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
    var url = tab.url;
    if (isUrl(url)) {
        chrome.pageAction.show(tab.id);

    }

});

function isUrl(url) {
    if (url.includes('show_bug.cgi?id'))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

The main issue is i am not able to get the string coming on webpage. After fetching from webpage i need to show on extension popup.html

Comment: You're using obsolete API. Replace chrome.extension.onRequest -> chrome.runtime.onMessage, chrome.tabs.sendRequest -> chrome.tabs.sendMessage. Also make sure you've reloaded the web tabs and the extension itself on chrome://extensions page after editing your code.

Comment: still same issue

Comment: Use devtools to debug the code. Open devtools for the tab, switch to `Sources`, then `Content scripts` panel, find your content script, set a breakpoint in the listener, then open the popup and see what happens. Maybe your tab doesn't run any content scripts at all (there are several reasons for that).

Comment: have verified action request is not listening in content.js ( chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener)

Comment: You probably mean it listens but doesn't receive. Do you open the popup in a separate tab? Anyway, it's impossible to guess what's wrong based on the provided info. Maybe you can make a screen recording or upload the actual extension zip.

Comment: Did you actually replace chrome.tabs.sendRequest -> chrome.tabs.sendMessage as noted in my comment above? Sounds like you didn't.